# Duplicate label on x-axis, stacking bar chart (google charts)

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a stacking bar chart with Google Charts. The data is dynamic, so i wont be able to tell the values of the axises until the chart is made. My problem is that the x-axis sometimes fills in unnecessary labels, as shown in the attached screenshot (In this particular scenario i only have 4 sets of data, so the second label named '12' shouldn't really be there).

Any suggestions to how i can fix this, and also align the columns right above their respective labels?

[image: Duplicate label]

Here's some of the code, as requested. Been trying different variations in the options, without much success.

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Alfa');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Bravo');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Charlie');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Delta');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Echo');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Foxtrot');

        data.addRows(myDataSet);

        var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 563,
            series: {
                0: { color: '#F7464A' }, //Alfa
                1: { color: '#46BFBD' }, //Bravo
                2: { color: '#FDB45C' }, //Charlie
                3: { color: '#0971B2' }, //Delta
                4: { color: '#ab7967' }, //Echo
                5: { color: '#a3be8c' }  //Foxtrot
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
            isStacked: true,
            title: title,
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Week',
                format: '0'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Tasks'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
            document.getElementById('velocityBarChartDiv'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        $("#velocityBarChartDiv").show();
```

Comment: Can you share some code or craft a plunker?

Comment: Added some of the code now (the part i think is relevant)

Comment: Thanks for the updated information. I think a piece or two may still be missing, but see my answer attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was kind of a shot in the dark to piece this together without sample data nor fiddle/plunker playground, but I think the key point you'd like to focus on here is to change your `DataTable` to `arrayToDataTable`. Also, browsing through the docs, you may be slightly astray with your setup. Here is my example data setup

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
[
    ['X', 'Alfa', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot'],
    ['10', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5],
    ['11', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9],
    ['12', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13],
    ['13', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13]
]);
```

It was kind of tricky, but it appears as if the first array will be your categories, and the *first* value in each row will relate to the x axis label. If we ignore those first string values and substitute numeric values, I also experience the shifty x axis you are getting with the "doubled" values.

Anyways, I took what was here, crafted a fiddle, and I think the end result is what you are searching for

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zb6nq74v/)

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly! Im sorry for the bad description, im impressed you came up with a solution :) Much appreciated